# Regex for min 8 characters, one uppercase letter and min one number not on the beginning and the end of the string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

This is the description:

- must be at least 8 characters long
- string must contain at least one uppercase letter
- the number must divide the string into at least two character strings

Examples:

Bad strings: asdFghjk, 123aSdfghjk, asd6H

Matching string: asd3fGhjk

So far I got this:

```
^(?!(0-9))(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$(?!(0-9))
```

Comment: `(0-9)` matches `0-9` string, you should use `[0-9]` or `\d`. At the end, you need a lookbehind, `(?<!\d)`, but it will only work in Chrome and Node so far, that have ES2018 implemented. Use `(?!.*\d$)` at the start, after `^`.

Comment: what should be desired output for strings like `dgd3323hdhdh132asas` ?

Comment: @CodeManiac it matches the pattern. "the number must divide the string into at least two character strings" so numbers can make more than 2 character strings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hmm I put your suggestion like this "^(?!.*\d$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}(?!.*\d$)$". It matches given examples but it doesn't match string from the Code Maniac comment

Comment: @karlo1zg try this [`^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.{8,})(?:.*[a-zA-Z]+\d+[a-zA-Z]+)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/59rIat/1/)

Comment: `dgd3323hdhdh132asas` should not be matched, it has no uppercase letter. See https://regex101.com/r/B0DdjV/1

Comment: Oh, you are right. I was just looking at numbers if they create 2 or more strings. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the length of string manually and then

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?:[a-zA-Z]+?\d+[a-zA-Z]+?)+$
```

[image]

```js
let arr = ['asdFghjk','123aSdfghjk','asd6H','asd3fGhjk','aAs2323ASDdncnc','a1a1a1a1a1A','dgd3323hdhdh132asas']

let tester = (str) =>{
  return str.length > 7 && /^(?=.*[A-Z])(?:[a-zA-Z]+?\d+[a-zA-Z]+?)+$/.test(str)
}

arr.forEach(str=>{
  console.log(str, ' --> ',tester(str))
})
```